# Passing Down Information From Root Component (React Native, Redux, React Navigation and Push Notifications)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

In my main App.js, I wire up a component ('Setup') with React Navigation and run:
const ReduxNavigator = connect(Setup)

I then put this ReduxNavigator component into my main App component. This wires up React Navigation with Redux.

I'm now setting up push notifications. This entails putting a bunch of listener components onto the root component (either root component works).

How do I handle the information the listeners provide, either passing it down as a prop or giving it to the global state, so that the rest of my app can access it? I may also like to navigate based on these listeners (e.g. on push notification opened). How would I do this?

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';

import Navigator from './src/Navigator'
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const { store } = configureStore() 

class Setup extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    }

    onOpened(openResult) {
      // where do I pass this information?
      // this.setState() doesn't workk
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Navigator 
                navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                state: this.props.nav,
            })} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    nav: state.nav
});

const ReduxNavigator = connect(mapStateToProps,  { /* importing actions here doesn't work */ })(Setup);

export default class App extends Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ReduxNavigator/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to access dispatch in the App root component. Start by moving the listeners and component lifecycle events to the App component...

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.store = store // <--- add this
        OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
}

onOpened = (openResult) => { // <--- make this is an arrow function 
      this.store.dispatch({type: "set_value", payload: "hello"}) // <--- dispatch stuff to your reducers
}
```

also, change "store" to "this.store" in the Provider:

```
<Provider store={this.store}>
```

Hope that helps someone (and hope it's not bad practice..)